# Toolbar and DrawerLayout - Up-Navigation opens drawer

Tags: android

My Up-Navigation is not working. The "Back"-Arrow is displayed in my `WinnerListActivity`, but on click it's not returning to the parents `MainActivity`, instead it opens my navigation drawer. None of the Log()-Methods are triggered. I'm quite sure it has something to do with my `ActionBarDrawerToggle`, but I can't figure out what's wrong. Is there anything missing?

**AndroidManifest:**

```
<activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name=".activity.WinnerListActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:parentActivityName=".activity.MainActivity" />
```

**WinnerListActivity:**

```
public class WinnerListActivity extends NavigationActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_winner_list);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Log.i(TAG, "item: " + item.getItemId());
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**NavigationActivity:**

```
public class NavigationActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);

        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);

        toggle.syncState();
        toggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.i(TAG, "setToolbarNavigationClickListener");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**activity_winner_list.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

                <include layout="@layout/include_toolbar_cover" />
                <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar />
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView />
        </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Your setup's a little odd, but you would need to call `setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false)` on the toggle somewhere to disable the drawer toggling. Also, the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method won't be called when clicking that toggle, since you've used the constructor that takes a `Toolbar`.

Comment: That kind of works and now triggers the `setToolbarNavigationClickListener` where I can call `NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask()`, which brings me back to the parents activity. Is that the intended behaviour? You say my setup is odd..you're talking about the layout? I'm in for any improvements!

Comment: Nah, not the layout; just how you're subclassing. No biggie. Anyhoo, yeah, the toggle overrides the standard home button functionality. I'd have to check, but I'm pretty sure you're gonna have to handle that yourself, just like you are, if you've got a toggle set. Though, it might be easier to implement the toggle only in the subclasses where it's needed, depending on your desired setup.

Comment: I just had a look, and it seems that you can preserve the default up navigation behavior if you use the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` constructor that does not take a `Toolbar`. However, in that case, you would have to implement the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method to make the toggle work. Just FYI.